# New installed ubuntu16.04 taking long time to boot

Tags: boot, 16.04

My Lenovo thinkpad L420 laptop's configuration:

processor-intel-i5 2.5GHz 
Ram - 4 GB

I am first time using Ubuntu and having trouble with startup, it's taking long time to boot.

Here are the time taken by different process:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
     44.108s dev-sda5.device
     42.088s grub-common.service
     40.638s networking.service
     40.203s apport.service
     40.163s speech-dispatcher.service
     40.075s irqbalance.service
     39.853s ondemand.service
     37.968s ModemManager.service
     33.219s apparmor.service
     22.820s thermald.service
     21.114s systemd-logind.service
     21.045s avahi-daemon.service
     20.754s pppd-dns.service
     20.754s systemd-user-sessions.service
     20.752s rsyslog.service
     20.526s console-setup.service
     12.026s lightdm.service
     11.285s NetworkManager.service
     10.522s accounts-daemon.service
```

How can I solve the issues?